# Errors with firebase_database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, androidx

I'm trying to build an app login with firebase and flutter. When trying to run the app I get the following error messages:

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:10:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.NonNull; ^
>   symbol: class NonNull location: package androidx.annotation
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:11:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.Nullable; ^
>   symbol: class Nullable location: package androidx.annotation
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:233:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onMethodCall(final MethodCall
>   call, @nonnull final Result result) { ^ symbol: class NonNull
>   location: class FirebaseDatabasePlugin
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:185:
>   error: cannot find symbol String eventType, @nonnull DataSnapshot
>   snapshot, String previousChildName) { ^ symbol: class NonNull
>   location: class FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:199:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onCancelled(@nonnull
>   DatabaseError error) { ^ symbol: class NonNull location: class
>   FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:207:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onChildAdded(@nonnull
>   DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) { ^ symbol: class
>   NonNull location: class FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:212:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onChildRemoved(@nonnull
>   DataSnapshot snapshot) { ^ symbol: class NonNull location: class
>   FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:217:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onChildChanged(@nonnull
>   DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) { ^ symbol: class
>   NonNull location: class FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:222:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onChildMoved(@nonnull
>   DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) { ^ symbol: class
>   NonNull location: class FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:227:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onDataChange(@nonnull
>   DataSnapshot snapshot) { ^ symbol: class NonNull location: class
>   FirebaseDatabasePlugin.EventObserver
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:166:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onComplete(@nullable
>   DatabaseError error, @nonnull DatabaseReference ref) { ^ symbol: class
>   Nullable location: class
>   FirebaseDatabasePlugin.DefaultCompletionListener
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:166:
>   error: cannot find symbol public void onComplete(@nullable
>   DatabaseError error, @nonnull DatabaseReference ref) { ^ symbol: class
>   NonNull location: class
>   FirebaseDatabasePlugin.DefaultCompletionListener
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:333:
>   error: cannot find symbol public Transaction.Result
>   doTransaction(@nonnull MutableData mutableData) { ^ symbol: class
>   NonNull
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:331:
>   error: cannot find symbol @nonnull ^ symbol: class NonNull 14 errors
>
> The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities
>   in this Flutter app. See [...] for more information on
>   the problem and how to fix it.
>
> Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I don't know which files would be helpful for troubleshooting. If you need something please tell me.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It says that you might have AndroidX incompatibilities you should look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration) and make the AndroidX migration if you haven't already done it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
What fixed it was adding these two lines to the grade.properties file:


`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`